# 2 event handler calling one jquery method

Tags: jquery, css

I have something like this:

```
$(".BWTabVerticalTitle").on("click", function () { alert('You pressed enter!'); });
```

and something like this:

```
        $(".BWTabVerticalTitle").keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                alert('You pressed enter!');
            }
        });
```

Now, I would like to combine these 2, to one statement which calls that function.
May be something like this:

```
        $(".BWTabVerticalTitle").on("click", function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            alert('You pressed enter!');
        }
        }).keypress();
```

The goal is to activate the function whith the ENTER-key and a click event, but my idea does not work...

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $(".BWTabVerticalTitle").bind('click keydown', function(e) {
     if (e.which === 13) {
        alert('enter!')
     }
     else { alert('click') }
});
```